# I'm interested in websocket/struts2 integration

Tags: struts2, websocket

I think I would like to see/make a very simple web based program using struts2 and websockets to demonstrate the use of websockets, probably a very basic chat client.

I am using a browser which has web sockets enabled (firefox with a tweak).  Have Glassfish 3.1 configured to enable websockets.

Anyone with any experience on where to look or what to do... or perhaps something working with struts2 and websockets no matter how simple would be fantastic.

Comment: Unrelated to web sockets : struts2-showcase -> Ajax Chat

Comment: No I can make a chat system, I'm just interested in web sockets.  I'll rewrite the question to stress that chat isn't really a requirement just sharing strings seemed pretty straight forward.  I found an example with JSF, but don't know it well.  I'll follow it though if need be.

Comment: @Quaternion please give the JSF link. Also, have you found a solution yet for Struts2 + websockets ?

Comment: If I recall correctly glassfish provided a websocket chat demo application. This is what I used to get started, that was some time ago, sorry can't provide link right now. If it has not been updated I remember having issues selecting the right version, it was an older one that was correct and some newer ones did not work. Hopefully this has been corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

roshanpaiva has a blog post on [Integrating Atmosphere (WebSockets) and Appfuse (struts2, spring, hibernate etc)](http://roshanpaiva.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/integrating-atmosphere-websockets-and-appfuse-struts2-spring-hibernate-etc/)

Comment: +1 I didn't know this existed. Since this is for fun I'd like to try working directly with the web socket API however Atmosphere looks like a very good solution.

Comment: @Quaternion So do you made something in Struts2? if you have something, please show me the example, so I can see how it can be integrated :) Thanks. Cause I searched a lot, and even looked at the example below, but I can understand how it works :)

Comment: Well... I haven't really been able to figure out "integration", but could possibly provide a side by side example of both working in the same project. I meditated on the issue and there is sort of an impedance mismatch between web sockets and traditional http requests served by... well any request based framework. The two systems will work independently and the logic will flow back together at the business tier. But they are a different means of request so there isn't much reuse from within struts2.

Comment: Ok, if there isn't a problem, I want to look at this example to get some sort of imagination on it. Thanks for the clarification. :)